# Laravel : Image not uploaded

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I have a four image field in my form for different use. When I try to upload images on two fields `image_one`and `image_two` sometimes it uploads `image_one` and sometimes only `image_two`

My controller code:

```
if(Input::file('image_one'))
{
    $image_one = $post->storePostPicture($request->file('image_one'));

    if($image_one !== false) {
        $post->image_one = $image_one;
        $post->save();
    }
}


if(Input::file('image_two'))
{
    $image_two = $post->storePostPicture($request->file('image_two'));
    if($image_two !== false) {
        $post->image_two = $image_two;
        $post->save();
    }
}
```

And my `storePostPicture`    function in model :

```
public function storePostPicture($image) {
    if($image instanceof \Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile && $image->isValid() && $image->isReadable()) {
        $filePath = 'public/images/user' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'post';
        if(!File::exists(storage_path('app' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $filePath))) {
            File::makeDirectory(storage_path('app' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $filePath), 0755, true);
        }
        $imageName = sha1(time().time()) . ".". $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        if($image->storeAs($filePath, $imageName) !== false) {
            $path = "/storage/images/user/post/";
            return $path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $imageName;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you tested with same pictures? Could be a size problem.

Comment: @AliÖzen try with all possibilities.

Comment: * sometimes it upload `image_one` and sometimes only `image_two`* uh, as in, the field value is empty? could you post your `form` element on the resulting html? if its size issue, perhaps you will need to chunk your post request using [`multipart/form-data` as `enctype`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_enctype.asp).

Comment: Using on POSTMAN

Answer (score 2):

In your migration table, make sure you have made all the image fields nullable:

```
$table->string('image_one')->nullable();
$table->string('image_two')->nullable();
...
```

Also, save your post model after collecting all the data.

```
if(Input::file('image_one'))
{
    $image_one = $post->storePostPicture($request->file('image_one'));

    if($image_one !== false) {
        $post->image_one = $image_one;
    }
}


if(Input::file('image_two'))
{
    $image_two = $post->storePostPicture($request->file('image_two'));
    if($image_two !== false) {
        $post->image_two = $image_two;
    }
}  

$post->save(); //saving the post model here
```